# Why Import Wizards cannot import Opportunities?

Tags: opportunity, data-import-wizard

I'm new to salesforce and I'm preparing the 401 certification.

I'm wondering why Import Wizards can not import Opportunities. Is there some specific reason or is it only an *ipse dixit* limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the [Data Import How To's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnobS_RgN7JZaD_Fq8uh3b2AA8olsj1Qk) video series on YouTube for a better understanding of how to prepare and import data into a SF Org along with which tools to use for particular types of data. While it's difficult to say exactly "why" Opportunities aren't supported at this time by the standard wizards, after viewing the videos, I suspect you may have a better idea of possible reasons for it.

When you consider the complex relationships between Opportunity, Accounts, Contacts, Opportunity Line Items, Product2, PriceBook2, Users, OpportunityTeams, etc., plus other custom objects that exist in many orgs, just preparing the data for import can be a complex and rather tedious task that's not at all simple compared to importing other types of data. I strongly suspect that's the reasoning behind Opportunity not being supported by Salesforce's built-in record import tools.

Fortunately "why" won't be on the exam. ;)

Comment: Link no longer works but I guess can search the How To somewhere else on youtube eh

Answer (score 0):

You can say that its a system limitation for now. I can't speak as to 'why', exactly, but this is a known limitation. In order to import Opportunites you would need to use a tool like the Excel Connector or the Data Loader. See: Tools and Toolkits.

And feel free to vote for this idea as well: [Importing Opportunities.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqj1AAC)